# jstl variable as index of associative arrays

Tags: jstl

I have values of a properties file loaded into object (array?). for example in my application.properties file i have

```
confirm.email.msg=A confirmation email has been sent.
```

in my jsp file, I can access that as follows

```
<c:out value="${pageScope.properties['confirm.email.msg']}"></c:out>
```

Everything works fine up this point. 
But instead of hard coding the the key name I want to use the value from a request object. for example, the string (key) "confirm.email.msg" is the value of "message". which I can print like this

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.message}"></c:out>
```

now if i combine this like this

```
<c:out value="${pageScope.properties['${requestScope.message}']}"></c:out>
```

It doesn't work. I think i would need an extra pair of quotation. not sure how to do that. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using

```
 <c:out value="${pageScope.properties[requestScope.message]}" />
```

or simply

```
${pageScope.properties[requestScope.message]}
```

Comment: You mean `<c:out value="${pageScope.properties[requestScope.message]}" />`.